# Android browser scroll to top when I tap on text field

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone

I am developing a website and I have an issue when developing the responsive (mobile) view.

I have a "contact us" form on my website. 
My issue is, when I access my web from my android browser, tap on the input text field, the page will scroll up and the keyboard is dismissed.
But when I access my website form IOS(iphone), there's no problem/issue as above. I can write text in my text field.

What I want to know is, it supposed work like the iphone does? There's no scroll to top.

I got stuck on this for hours, and I would very appreciate if anyone could help me on this.
I'm sorry for my bad english grammar :)

Comment: $(selector).scrollTop(position) or window.scrollTo(100, 0);

Comment: Thanks agent for your feedback. But, what I should with that function? Thanks.. Andi